# Format perl regex capture groups

Tags: regex, bash, perl

Consider the following situation.  It is hypothetical, but demonstrates a general thing I would like accomplished.

Suppose I have a file, which has one or more lines.  On each line, it may have one or more instances of `[name]`=`[value]`, where `[name]` is some variable name and `[value]` is some value.  Suppose further that each of these are matched by `/[a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]+/`.

What I would like is a perl expression that will print out each match, formatted in a particular way.  My intent is to use this on the command line to parse data from files.  A hypothetical solution, made invalid because perl doesn't actually accept this syntax: `print m/([a-zA-Z]+)=([0-9]+)/name: \1, value: \2\n/g`, which, when run on each line, in our ideal world, would print out each match from each line like `name:[name], value:[value]`, each formatted match on its own line.

For example, consider this input file test.txt:

```
blah blah count=5 blah i=1
books=2 blah
blah fairies=87 water=0
```

Suppose we then type our magic command into bash, something like the following:

```
perl -n -e 'print m/([a-zA-Z]+)=([0-9]+)/name: \1, value: \2\n/g' test.txt
```

(It might be more reasonable to require some kind of loop over all returned matches, but hopefully you get the idea.)

It would print the following:

```
name: count, value: 5
name: i, value: 1
name: books, value: 2
name: fairies, value: 87
name: water, value: 0
```

I realize that this syntax does not actually work, but I would like to accomplish the same thing in as brief a piece of perl as possible.  I hope to be able to use it occasionally on the command line to find and format text.  I've written my own ruby script, but its a bit buggy, and not included in a standard environment (or in anybody's environment but my own).  Anybody know some perl secrets?

Comment: One possible solution might be if there's a compact way to return a bunch of matches, then apply a find/replace to each of them, and print them out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were pretty close. ;-)

```
$ perl -ne 'print "name: $1, value: $2\n" while /([a-zA-Z]+)=([0-9]+)/g;' test.txt
name: count, value: 5
name: i, value: 1
name: books, value: 2
name: fairies, value: 87
name: water, value: 0
```

Edit: since your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301171/format-perl-regex-capture-groups/34301592#comment56345980_34301592) seemed to indicate that shorter is better, here's a version with a few characters shaved off:

```
$ perl -lne 'print "name: $1, value: $2" while /([A-Z]+)=(\d+)/gi' test.txt
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  Also, it seems not to require the semicolon at the end, which marginally reduces the number of characters I'll need to type when I use it.

Comment: @Erhannis That's right---semicolons are optional for the last statement in a block. However, see my updated answer if you want to shed a few more characters.

Comment: Don't chase compact.  If you are using it often enough, then write a script instead.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be - consider selecting your vars into a hash.

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $/;
my %stuff = <> =~ m/(\w+)=(\d+)/g;
print Dumper \%stuff ;
```

Should do approximately what you want.